# Swift3 how do I get the value of a specific key in a string?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I've got a server response returning

```
(
    {
    agreementId = "token.virtual.4321";
    city = AMSTERDAM;
    displayCommonName = "bunch-of-alphanumeric";
    displaySoftwareVersion = "qb2/ene/2.7.14";
    houseNumber = 22;
    postalCode = zip;
    street = "";
    }
)
```

how do I get the value of agreementId? response['agreementId'] is not working. i've tried some example code with .first but I cannot get it working.

Some extra information, I do a http call to a server with alamofire. I try to parse the json to a constant response:

```
let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
```

However that returns a error message

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1083600) to 'NSDictionary' (0x108386c).
```

So now parse the json to an array, which seems to be working. The code above is what

```
let response = JSON as! NSArry
print(response)
```

spits out.

Now I only need to retrieve the value from the key "agreementId" and I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: what is `response`, is a dictionary retrieved by parsing the json? Debug your code and inspect what `response` *actually* is.

Comment: What type is the variable JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift you need to use Swift's native type `Array/[]` and `Dictionary/[:]` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, if you specify the type like above means more specific then the compiler won't complain. Also use optional wrapping with `if let` or `guard let` to prevent crash.

```
if let array = JSON as? [[String:Any]] {//Swift type array of dictionary
    if let dic = array.first {
        let agreementId = dic["agreementId"] as? String ?? "N/A"//Set default value instead N/A
        print(agreementId)
        //access the other key-value same way
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you having more than one object in your array then you need to simply loop through the array to access each dictionary of array.

```
if let array = JSON as? [[String:Any]] {//Swift type array of dictionary
    for dic in array {
        let agreementId = dic["agreementId"] as? String ?? "N/A"//Set default value instead N/A
        print(agreementId)
        //access the other key-value same way
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution. And thanks for the other pointers, helps me a lot as swift newb

Comment: @JeroenSwets Welcome mate :)